# Using wildcards in sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

The following command works as expected and shows the number of databases in the redis.conf file. What I need to do is to change it to 32 and save it back to the same file using a single command.

```
# grep ^databases redis.conf | awk '{print $2}'
16
```

Following command works only if the number is 16. How do I change the unknown number to 32?

```
sed -i 's/databases\ 16/databases\ 32/' redis.conf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `[0-9]*` or `\d` or the respective POSIX character class (`[:digit:]`). Like so:

```
sed -i 's/databases\ [0-9]*/databases\ 32/' redis.conf
```

Note: `\d` may or may not need an additional backslash because of shell escaping.
Also note: different flavors of `sed` (and `awk`) exist.

For highest portability I think `[0-9]` and `[:digit:]` are the best choice. To have a certain number of repetitions matched, repeat the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be guaranteed to be two digits only?

```
sed -i 's/^databases [0-9][0-9]/databases 32/' redis.conf
```